# Upgrading parts on Fuji Panic 3.0

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, gears, replacement

I want to upgrade some gear parts on my current bike, which is a Fuji Panic 3.0
I don't really know if it will be compatible though.
The bike: http://www.bikepedia.com/QuickBike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=2006&brand=Fuji&model=Panic+3.0

Parts i will be equipping/replacing with:

- Shimano Alivio ST-M4000 Shifters 3 x 9-speed
- Shimano Deore RD-M592 rear derallieur MTB SGS
- Shimano Deore FD-M590 front derallieur Top Swing OR FD-M591 Down Swing
- Shimano Alivio CS-HG300 Cassette 9-speed
- Shimano Alivio FC-M4000 Crankset MTB 40/30/22, 9-speed

Parts are not final, i can for example replace the M592 with a M591 for about €5 cheaper

I also noticed that some of the parts come in diffrent versions and designs, for example the cassette comes with different ammount of cogs: 11-28, 11-32, 11-34, etc.

How do i know which designs/versions to use? The Crankset (some length in mm), Front derrallieur (some angle in degrees) and rear cassette (ammount of cogs) have diffrent versions

Is there any other parts i would need to buy? I was thinking i could re-use the rest on the bike.

Everything on the bike except the shifters are original. I could also just buy Claris shifters and use current parts but since i bought the bike used and the gears seem somewhat clunky i decided it might be best to replace the gears instead.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

/C

EDIT: The parts will cost around €160

EDIT2: Thanks for all the answers, I will be buying a new bike.

Comment: Why? At that point, you've basically upgraded everything but the frame and fork. Doesn't seem like all the best of an investment.

Comment: http://sheldonbrown.com and http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/ are recommended reading.

Comment: Your link implies its a $600 bike, so a grade above walmart but nothing special, and its now 10 years old.  The combined cost of all your parts is likely to be about that, if not more. (supply chains are weird like that)    So do price it, then go try some new bikes that cost about the same amount, and either sell this one to offset the costs, or keep it as a spare or wet day bike as-is.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the answers, i will take it into consideration!
The parts will cost me about 160€ while a new bike with similar (gear) parts will cost 650€ or more, so thats why i thought it would be wise to upgrade instead so save some money. I beleive i can get the bike in mint condition for under €300 including the parts mentioned in the question.

I will look into those links by ojs, but lets say i was about to upgrade the parts on current bike. What are the things to think of, concerning compability between those parts, since diffrent versions exist?

Comment: You are asking very general questions, and sheldonbrown.com has a very general introduction to bicycle technology and maintenance. You should read through it. Also, if the parts are worn but not broken, you can very probably get good result with new chain, cassette and shifter cables.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I will be buying a new bike.

Comment: Please add that as an answer, and then click "accept" else this question will keep looping around.   Enjoy your new bike!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers, I will be buying a new bike.